# UV Maps rendering with 90 degree skew

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, uv-image-editor

I'm a 3DSMax head from way back adopting Blender as my tool of choice. For the most part, I'm bumbling through, but have one strange issue.

When trying to UV map a very simple object, I've been using the *Project From View* tool using orthogonal viewpoints, but what I see in the UV Map editor is not reflected in the viewport preview or render. It seems to be skewing by 90 degrees, or swapping U with V. Here's a screen snap:

[image: UV Map Interface]

The selected face should have 7 or so boards running crossways, but instead it has 2 boards running lengthways. What shows up in the viewport is the bottom left corner of the image. The vertex coords also seem nonsensical:

[image: Top Left]
[image: Top Right]

I'd expect to see a consistent Y value for both verts, and a low X for the left vert, then a slightly higher X for the right vert.

I'm not sure the shader is the issue, but just in case, here's the shader I'm using for the material:

[image: Shady]

Nothing fancy. I've tried playing around with the rotation in the mapping node, and I can get it to look okay on the top face by rotating 90 degrees around Z, but I can't get the front face to do anything but stretch. I've also tried deleting and recreating the UV map from scratch.

My best guess is that I'm doing something silly, or I've missed a vital step - is anyone able to better enlighten me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to switch your *Image Texture* node from *Box* to *Flat*, otherwise it won't project the island on the correct axis (from what I understand it looks like the *Box* option will unwrap 90° on Z compared to a default top *Project from View*):

[image]

Comment: Outstanding, that's fixed it! Much appreciated.